# Finding the conflicting upstream merge in Git?

Tags: git

Our team uses a Git workflow where we branch from "master" into a feature branch (for example "F-1234"), do our work and then merge our feature branch back into "integration."

Occasionally there are merge conflicts when merging into integration.   We are expected to fix these conflicts IN OUR FEATURE BRANCH, but we are not allowed to merge "integration" back into our feature branch.  We have to go find the other feature branch (say, "F-4567") and merge that branch.

My question:   How can I look back into integration and find out what other feature branch is causing the problem?

Comment: You could rebase on top of integration but this isn't always possible, especially if collaborating with another dev on a feature branch. It sounds like you have a procedural issue rather than a technical one. It may be worth asking the question of the team leader to figure out what they expect you to do. Perhaps they will realise they have put forward a flawed workflow, with those restrictions being in place.

Comment: Yeah, rebasing isn't an option, we've been told to do it this way.

Comment: Sounds horrific to be honest. What happens if feature-x wants to go out before feature-y, but has had feature-y merged into it already?

Comment: @bcmcfc - then there's pain.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell "them" that "their" process is making it harder on the developers than things need to be.

Meanwhile, for a given file that is conflicted (e.g. `foobar.c`), you can start with something like this to identify potential conflict sources:

```
git log --all --merges integration -- foobar.c
```

This should show all merge commits on the integration branch that introduced changes to that file. Hopefully, in the common case, there will only be one branch that modified that file, but you may have to examine several branches in some cases.

Comment: This pretty much gave me what I needed:   "git log --all --pretty=oneline --merges origin/integration"   Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called "git-imerge" that, essentially, performs every possible merge combination between two branches. At the end, you will keep only the style you want (either rebase, or merge, etc).

One of the nice things about the tool is that it identifies exactly which two commits conflict and lets you solve the problem on the smallest commit-pair that has the problem. Then, you can propagate the resolution forward. It's a pretty nifty tool (when it works! I did have some issues with it).